# Could not load the nibName issue (xamarin)

Tags: c#, xamarin, macos-sierra, nib

We start to prepare project with generic solution for few apps using `Xamarin` studio (the idea is to let all our apps use same "Core" components).

We started from preparing general "*Core*" with base functionality. Also we add "subCore" - libraries with functionality specific to each platform (iOS, android, windows etc).

Currently setup such structure for `Android` and `iOS`.

During second step of implementation for `macOS`, we faced with few blocking points.

The problem appear when we try to configure (in way described above) structure for `macOS` platform.

I was able to create `macOS` *class Library* with components that should be reused in apps (for now this is just 1 class with `xib` file). But, when I want to use this package (with `xib` inside) in `macOS` target, got exception:

> External Modification Warnings: Debugger attached to process.
>
> Application Specific Information:
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[NSNib
>   _initWithNibNamed:bundle:options:] could not load the nibName: MainViewController in bundle (null).' terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type NSException abort() called

After some investigating, found that `Mac Build server is not converting xibs into nibs`, so this `nib` file is just missing in package created by `Xamarin`.

Additional testing info, based on proposed solutions found in `Xamarin` forum:

- *rename, recreate, reposition of xib file in project* - not resolve the issue
- *recreate project* - not resolve the issue
- *check `Build action` in property is set to `InterfaceDefinition` (also check all other possible variants)* - not resolve the issue

---

I found **[this post](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/7076/#Comment_7076)**, with root cause exactly as I have:

> Mac Build server is not converting xibs into nibs.

According to discussion on this post, issue should be fixed, but I still faced with this.

Can some one advice how to fix described problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who faced same issue, please install

[xamarin.ios-10.13.0.27.pkg](https://bosstoragemirror.azureedge.net/wrench/macios-mac-master/34/340963fd9659331158f015a309a3161fafadbe29/xamarin.ios-10.13.0.27.pkg)

and

[xamarin.mac-3.7.0.27.pkg](https://bosstoragemirror.azureedge.net/wrench/macios-mac-master/34/340963fd9659331158f015a309a3161fafadbe29/xamarin.mac-3.7.0.27.pkg)

This build include fix for described problem.

For more, visit [this page](https://jenkins.mono-project.com/view/Xamarin.MaciOS/job/xamarin-macios-builds-master/).